# Storing user data to file (text boxes, Check buttons etc)

Tags: c#

I have a GUI (C#), to configure some hardware attached to the computers serial port.
I want to include the option that enables the user to save all configuration data from textboxes, Checkboxes etc into some filetype. Then I want the user to have the option to reopen the filetype to update textboxes, combobox indexes, checkboxes etc in the GUI.
In total I have about 100 types of textboxes, comboboxes checkboxes in this GUI.

Whould XML files be too inconvenient? Other better ways to save this user configuration?

Comment: XML is definetly good for that

Answer (score 0):

This is a good situation where [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) becomes very useful, instead of each of your controls holding the value have them bind to a class that holds the value as one of its properties.

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string FilePath {get; set;}
    public bool SomeSpecialOption {get; set;}
    //...
}
```

Now when you set up your class you can set up bindings all you need to do is load or save your single `MySettings` class and use whatever form of serialization you are comfortable with (XML, protobuf, ect...).

This makes saving and loading your settings very easy too

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    { 
         InitializeComponent(); //Assumes the binding was set up via the gui to the bindingSource "settingsBindingSource"

         settingsBindingSource.DataSource = new MySettings();
    }

    //...

    private void SaveSettings(string path)
    {
         var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
         using(var writer = new StreamWriter(path);
         {
              ser.Serialize(writer, (MySettings)settingsBindingSource.DataSource);
         }
    }

    private void LoadSettings(string path)
    {
         var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
         using(var reader = new StreamReader(path);
         {
               settingsBindingSource.DataSource = (MySettings)ser.Deserialize(reader);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, I will look into this and try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the *save state* / *restore state* operations more explicit, you may choose to use the **Memento pattern** in your design.

[The memento pattern, Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

The **originator** of the memento would be your window. The memento (**the state**) would be a well-defined data structure (you should **define a class** on this purpose) containing the data from *text boxes*, *check boxes* etc. The originator is responsible with **populating that data structure** (the memento) and with reading it at some later time in order to **restore its state**.

Now, your problem is how to *persist / serialize* & *hydrate / deserialize* the memento itself. Concerning this, you can choose any format you want, but take care to encapsulate the serialization logic within a **well-defined module**. E.g. *MyMementoXmlSerializer*, *MyMementoJsonSerializer* or *MyMementoBinarySerializer*. These modules (classes) would share a common interface, **MyMementoSerializer**.

Now, **JSON** is another *human-readable* text format, you may want to consider it. Take a look on how simple is to serialize objects into the JSON format using the **Json.NET** toolkit. The BinarySerializer from the .NET framework is another choice, though... it is not human-readable :)

[The Json.NET toolkit](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

To summarize, I would choose the JSON format & the JSON.NET toolkit for the purpose of simplicity, but also design the solution using the **memento pattern**, the **MyMementoSerializer** interface etc.

Comment: Thank you andrei. The JSON toolkit is powerfull.